# Python: Error with my path (r"D:\Users\lsi\2_TRIALS\18_TRIAL1\myfile.txt")

Tags: python, path

I do not understand why my path make an error:
r"D:\Users\lsi\2_TRIALS\1_TRIAL1\myfile.txt"

when I use an other path, it works:
r"C:\Users\lsi.PRT-001\Desktop\myfile.txt"

come from using D driver?

```
def traduction():
    # fichier_traduction = r"C:\Users\lsi.PRT-001\Desktop\myfile.txt"
    fichier_traduction = r"D:\Users\lsi\2_TRIALS\1_TRIAL1\myfile.txt"
    file = open(fichier_traduction, newline='', encoding='utf-8')
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    liste = []
    tupl = ()
    sous_tuple = ()
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 0:
            l = len(row[0])
            if row[0][:1] =='#':
                sous_tuple = sous_tuple + (row[0][5:],)
            if row[0][3:4] =='i':
                tupl = tupl + (sous_tuple,row[0][7:l-1],)
                sous_tuple = ()
            elif row[0][3:4] =='s':
                tupl = tupl + (row[0][8:l-1],)
        else:
            liste.append(tupl)
            tupl = ()
    return liste
```

```
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\intensetbm-etool\export\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "D:\Users\jl3\DevSpace\intensetbm-etool\export\views.py", line 233
    file = open(fichier_traduction, newline='', encoding='utf-8')
                                                                ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Comment: Please show the error message and the code that produces the error.

Comment: Have you checked the indentation in terms of the spaces/tabs used?

Comment: Your error message indicates that the error is not the path. It says `TabError` so the file exists and the error has nothing to do with the path of this file. The problem is related to the use of tabs, spaces.

Comment: yes but as C: path works, I think error is not 'really' indentation but an error on D: path declaration

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your disk/path like this before pointing your file :

```
import os
os.chdir("D:/blabla")
```